# In codeigniter i am send a php variable from view page to controller through the <a> tag, but i can't display value in controller page

Tags: php, codeigniter

> this is my view page code

```
<td><a href="<?php echo site_url("Customer/viewpatient/?id=".$id); ?>" ><button type="button" name="admit" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" id="btnViewCust">Admit</button></a></td>
```

> this is my controller function

```
public function viewpatient()
{

        $data['id'] = $this->input->post('id');
        echo $data['id'];

}
```

Comment: If you change it to something like this `<?php echo site_url("Customer/viewpatient/" . $id); ?>` then you can use `echo $this->uri->segment(3);` 3 would be id http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html#CI_URI::segment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use this  $this->input->get()

```
   public function viewpatient()
    {

    $data['id'] = $this->input->get('id');
    echo $data['id'];

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

On Your View

```
<td>
    <a href="<?php echo site_url("Customer/viewpatient/" . $id); ?>" ><button type="button" name="admit" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" id="btnViewCust">Admit</button>
    </a>
</td>
```

Controler Function

```
public function viewpatient($id = 0)
{

    echo $id;

}
```

You are sending value in get request and catching in post . and change your link this way .